# WPF Clickonce in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: wpf, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, clickonce

We have a WPF Clickonce application, whcih is deployed in Server. It is working perfectly in IE. The application started installing on single click. But in Firefox and Chrome, the file was downloaded. How to overcome this? I know there are some plug-ins which will allow this as IE.

But my question is, Can I add these plugins into my application pre-requisites? Or what is the good approach to do that. Is there anyway that I could install the plugins by detecting the browsers before starting the clickonce app? I don't want my end users to do that.

Comment: what file are you talking about? Setup.exe or app.application? If the latter one - i guess you need to set correct MIME type on the server for it in this case (executable).

Answer (score 0):

Even if you find a way to embed plugins into ClickOnce-bootstrapper ("pre-requisite") you'll have to tell user to run it explicitly. ClickOnce doesn't support installing of dependencies transparently. You'll have an .exe file which user need to run. Usually VS wizard generates an html page (publish.html) which has client code for detecting missing pre-requisites. But actually it detects only missing .NET. 
So you have to write some js-code for detecting missing/installed extensions for each browser you want to support.
Check this SO question: [Checking if user has a certain extension installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042548/checking-if-user-has-a-certain-extension-installed)

In anyway if a user has a link to .application and opens it in the browser then all pre-requisites will be ignored. As actually ClickOnce itself doesn't have such a feature as "pre-requisites" or "dependencies". It's just a helper for generating totally separated setup.exe bootstrapper.

Here links for extensions:

- Firefox addin for ClickOnce applications - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/microsoft-net-framework-assist/
- Google Chrome addin for ClickOnce applications - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eeifaoomkminpbeebjdmdojbhmagnncl