# Check to see if browser has Pinterest Pin it button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, pinterest

I have written a script to add a Pinterest button to most images on my site. The issue is that when someone has the [Chrome Pin it extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pin-it-button/gpdjojdkbbmdfjfahjcgigfpmkopogic?hl=en) enabled in their browser, the "pin it" button shows up twice for the user.

Is there anyway, in JavaScript, to check if the user has this extension enabled in their browser?

```
(function($) {

    $(function() {

      $('.container img').each(function() {
          if ($(this).parent('a')) {
              var $permalink = $(this).parent('a').attr('href');
          }
          else {
              var $permalink = $(location).attr('href');
          }


          var $permalink = $(location).attr('href'),
              $title = $('h1.product_name').text() || $('h2.header');

          var $linkhtml = $('<a/>', {
              'class':'pin-it-button pinme',
              'html': '<img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_gray_20.png" />',
              'count-layout': 'horizontal',
            'style': 'cursor:pointer; position:absolute; bottom:30px; left:0; border:0 none; opacity: 0.4;',
              'href': 'http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=' + $permalink  + '&media=' + $(this).attr('src') + '&description=' + $title
          });

          if ($(this).parent('a')) {
              $(this).addClass('pinme').parent('a').after($linkhtml);
          }
          else {
              $(this).addClass('pinme').after($linkhtml);
          }

          $('.pinme').hover(
            function() {
              if ($(this).hasClass('pin-it-button')) {
                console.log('hello');
                  $(this).css('opacity', '1');
              }
              else {
                  $(this).parent().siblings('.pin-it-button').css('opacity', '1');
              }
            }, function() {
              if ($(this).hasClass('pin-it-button')) {
                  $(this).css('opacity', '0.4');
              }
              else {
                  $(this).parent().siblings('.pin-it-button').css('opacity', '0.4');
              }
            }
          );


      });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042548/checking-if-user-has-a-certain-extension-installed this might help

Comment: You should just add `data-pin-no-hover="true"` to your images. Much easier.

Comment: @ZackArgyle, make that an answer, the info is worth it, you may also add one line of code that sets the attribute (just for the sake of completeness).

Comment: Happy to post an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The new Pinterest extension (2017)

injects a `<span>` hover button directly under `<body`:

```html
<span style="border-radius: 3px;
    text-indent: 20px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: url(&quot;data:image/svg+xml;base64,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&quot;) 3px 50% / 14px 14px no-repeat rgb(189, 8, 28);
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 8675309;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    top: 240px;
    left: 110px;
">Save</span>
```

So a simple check would be:

```
var pin = document.querySelector('body > span[style*="8675309"][style*="rgb(189, 8, 28)"]')
```

Or you can check for the entire background base64 string which contains the P logo.

---

#### Old answer for the old PinIt extension:

Examining a page with Pin It extension installed we can see that it adds its own attribute to `<body>`:

```html
<body data-pinterest-extension-installed="cr1.39.1">
```

It's easy to determine the presence of the attribute in js:

```
if (document.body.dataset.pinterestExtensionInstalled) {
    console.log("Pin It extension detected!");
}
```

Note that the attribute is added after the page has been loaded so you can't check it right in `DOMContentLoaded` event handler; make a pause with `setInterval` or use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

- Content script with `"run_at": "document_end"` or `"document_idle"` (the default mode):

  ```
  var PinItInstalled = undefined;

  new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      PinItInstalled = document.body.dataset.pinterestExtensionInstalled;
      this.disconnect();
  }).observe(document.body, {
      attributes: true,
      attributeFilter: ["data-pinterest-extension-installed"]
  });
  ```
- Content script with `"run_at": "document_start"`:

  ```
  var PinItInstalled = undefined;

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
          PinItInstalled = document.body.dataset.pinterestExtensionInstalled;
          this.disconnect();
      }).observe(document.body, {
          attributes: true,
          attributeFilter: ["data-pinterest-extension-installed"]
      });
  });
  ```

P.S. Don't forget to test what happens if the Pin It extension's option to show its button on hover is disabled.

Comment: It seems to me the `data-pinterest-extension-installed` attribute is not added anymore. Maybe a change in the lastest release on Chrome. Am I the only one?

Answer (score 2):

While detecting the presence of the extension or pinit.js on the page may be worthwhile, the easier solution is to simply add the data-pin-no-hover attribute to your images. This will tell the extension to ignore the images.

```
<img src="whatevz" data-pin-no-hover="true" />
```

There really isn't any reason to care if it is installed or not if the data-pin attribute is set.

The other option is to not create your own hover buttons, but use pinit.js that creates the hover buttons for you. See [the docs](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/widgets/pin-it/#global-configuration-options).

```
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  async defer
  data-pin-hover="true"
  src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"
></script>
```

Comment: I think it would make sense to add the code that sets the attribute to the first method, maybe something like `$(this).attr("data-pin-no-hover", "true")`.